# Как передать методом текст поля формы?

Tags: php, html, css

Есть поле, которое скрыто. При этом, помимо того, что оно скрыто, нужно, чтобы пользователь не мог его изменить даже путём изменения кода страницы. Я пытался использовать атрибут `disabled="true"`, но тогда текст этого поля не передаётся в переменную `$_POST`.

```
`<input type = "text" value = "<?php echo $_GET['id']?>"  name = "id" hidden = "true" disabled="true">`
```

Comment: Можно поставить свойство readonly, но через код страницы его все равно можно изменить

Comment: написать валидацию на стороне сервера...т е как бы не хотел клиент впихнуть вам что-то, больше того что вам на сервере нужно он не впихнет. А валидация на клиенте пишется чисто для удобства пользователя.

Comment: и вообще..зачем вам это нужно? если к вам могут слать запросы откуда угодно, то по любому на сервере проверяйте

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц нужно, чтобы там было поле идентификатора пользователя, отправляющего запрос

Comment: Это в сессии должно храниться, а не в поле на форме.

Comment: @u_mulder неправильно сформулировал. id пользователя. на который кликает администратор. Он хочет, допустим, поменять имя пользователя. на которого кликнул. Но он не должен никак менять его идентификатор. Примерно так

Comment: Ну тут надо только доверять администратору. Вы никак не сможете спрятать/запретить на редактирование поле. Только если строить костыли при заходе на страницу сохранять ИД юзера в сессию, при сабмите смотреть совпадают ли ИД, в общем как капча прям.

Comment: Ну и соответственно логировать действия администратора - такой-то такого-то числа изменил поле с .. на ..

Comment: Также если у вас какие-то есть группы (мало ли может МЛМ какой), то также проверять что администратор может редактировать пользователей в этой группе.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам так сильно нужно сопроводить свою страницу неизменными данными - зашифруйте их на стороне сервера и поместите в cookie. Тогда уж точно на стороне клиента (в браузере) данные никто не подменит, потому что не поймет что на что менять, и эти же данные гарантированно вернутся к Вам на сервер со следующим запросом, что позволит их расшифровать, перепроверить и утилизировать после использования. Хотя, честно говоря, не понимаю смысла такой операции.

> Он хочет, допустим, поменять имя пользователя. на которого кликнул. Но он не должен никак менять его идентификатор.

Ну так и сделайте на уровне кода обработчика неизменным значение ID пользователя, кто же Вам мешает-то? Ведь это **ВЫ** в контроллере-обработчике производите операции изменения данных. Соответственно, **ВЫ** и задаете "правила игры" - что можно поменять, а что нельзя! Если Вы в контроллере не напишите `$user->id = $_REQUEST['id']; $user->save();`, то ID пользователя **никак** не поменяется, даже если в запросе будет присутствовать новый ID пользователя.

**Update**

> Проблема в том что можно передать id совершенно иного пользователя и обновить его, а не того кого открыли на форме изначально.

Сопроводите критичные к изменению данные хэшем или ЭЦП со стороны сервера. При попытке изменения этих данных хэш не сойдется, и Вы сразу получите признак попытки корректировки критичных данных. Хотя опять же, если пользователь *имеет право* корректировать данные того пользователя, ID которого он подставил, - Вам-то какая разница? Это его область ответственности. А если *не имеет права* корректировать данные того пользователя, ID которого он вручную поменял, - то такие вещи режутся на уровне проверки прав на выполнение операции. Опять же, если Вы эти проверки реализовали - его "обрежет". И снова вопрос: Вам-то, как разработчику, что с того? В лог попытку записали, алерт админу отправили, дальше - область ответственности админа. А админа контролировать... Захочет - "ручками" прямо в базе все поправит, и хэш вручную посчитает, посмотрев исходники скриптов.

От этого спасение только одно - личная ЭЦП каждого участника корректировки и сплошное журналирование операций, как это реализовано в банковских системах при проведении платежей. Каждый оператор имеет личный ключ ЭЦП. Каждая операция проходит минимум через двух человек: оператор вводит, контролер проверяет. В каждый момент времени на любой документ наложено одновременно 2 различных ЭЦП. И ежесуточная сверка ведомостями проведения операций + материальная и уголовная ответственность за "нескладушки".

Но я не уверен, что Ваш случай заслуживает таких организационно-технических мероприятий.

Comment: Проблема в том что можно передать id __совершенно иного пользователя__ и обновить его, а не того кого открыли на форме изначально.

Comment: Обновил ответ...

Answer (score 0):

`<input type = "hidden" value = "<?php echo $_GET['id']?>"  name = "id">`

`<input type = "hidden" value = "<?php echo md5($_GET['id'].'еще что-то')?>"  name = "crypt_id">`

```
<?php
    if(md5($_POST['id'].'еще что-то') == $_POST['crypt_id']){
        // обрабатываем форму
    }
```

при смене `id` - отправлять AJAX на генерацию нового `md5($_GET['id'].'еще что-то')`

Comment: AJAX на генерацию нового хэша не проходит. В исходниках javascript на странице можно будет расковырять это и при необходимости запросить этот самый AJAX для любого ID. Если уж делать, то тут только один вариант: всю форму генерировать на строне сервера. Возможно, с генерированием "соли" ("еще что-то") случайным способом с сохранением в сессии. И включить "вариантивность" - IP, timestamp генерации, что-либо еще. Чтобы при разных сессиях (или даже в пределах одной и той же, но в разное время) получался разный хэш. Чтобы в "разрешенной" сессии не скопировали "правильный" хэш для подстановки.